# How to get values for one column from scenario outline as an array in Karate

Tags: api, request, karate, outline, scenarios

I have a request.json as below

```
    {
    "country":"#(country)",
    "states":["#(states)"]
    }
```

My feature file

```
    Scenario outline: test

    *def req = call('request.json')
    And request req
    When method post

    Examples:
    |country|states|
    |India|delhi,goa|
```

With above code I am getting as

```
    {
    "country":"India",
    "states":["delhi,goa"]
    }
```

But i want my request to look like below

```
    {
    "country":"India",
    "states":["delhi","goa"]
    }
```

Is there any direct way to get above request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change:

```
Examples:
|country|states!|
|India|['delhi','goa']|
```

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

Comment: It worked fine thanks
Only change is that in the request.json I have to remove [] for states
 "states":"#(states)"